# How to get the status and raise the event at the change of status?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following checkboxes on the page for class shedules. I want to grab the value of the checkbox that was checked when the page was loaded and is now unchecked when page is submitted. How can I do that in JavaScript?

```
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline" class="oddRow">
<td class="bold">0191</td>
<td class="bold">ART 1 (P)</td>
<td class="bold">S1</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td bgcolor="DarkGray" style="background-color:DarkGray">1<input type="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25325798" TITLE="0191.1 :  31/36&#xa;&nbsp;Thomas, Marc L" checked></td>
<td bgcolor="Indianred" style="background-color:Indianred">1*<input type="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25325799" TITLE="0191.2 :  36/36&#xa;&nbsp;Ericson, Daniel J"></td>
<td bgcolor="Indianred" style="background-color:Indianred">1*<input type="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25325800" TITLE="0191.3 :  36/36&#xa;&nbsp;Ericson, Daniel J"></td>
<td bgcolor="Indianred" style="background-color:Indianred">1*<input type="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25325801" TITLE="0191.4 :  37/36&#xa;&nbsp;Thomas, Marc L"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript code you tried.

Comment: onDomReady get the checked values. On submit get the checked values. Do what you want with those two collections.

Comment: I do not have any JavaScript yet. Thank you! I will read up on onDomReady and see if I can make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window.onload and then loop through the checkboxes looking for the checked ones.

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
    var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');

    for(var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++)
    {
        if(cbs[i].checked)
        {
            console.log(cbs[i].value);
        }
    }
}
</script>

</tr>
<tr valign="baseline" class="oddRow">
<td class="bold">0191</td>
<td class="bold">ART 1 (P)</td>
<td class="bold">S1</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td bgcolor="DarkGray" style="background-color:DarkGray">1<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25325798" TITLE="0191.1 :  31/36&#xa;&nbsp;Thomas, Marc L" checked></td>
<td bgcolor="Indianred" style="background-color:Indianred">1*<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25325799" TITLE="0191.2 :  36/36&#xa;&nbsp;Ericson, Daniel J"></td>
<td bgcolor="Indianred" style="background-color:Indianred">1*<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25325800" TITLE="0191.3 :  36/36&#xa;&nbsp;Ericson, Daniel J"></td>
<td bgcolor="Indianred" style="background-color:Indianred">1*<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25325801" TITLE="0191.4 :  37/36&#xa;&nbsp;Thomas, Marc L"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Phill! this is what I was looking for. Now I have array of all the checkboxes, I can work from here, all values I need are right there to use in tlist_sql.